# Reference package vignettes with Roxygen2

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, roxygen2

So, I'd like to reference one of my package vignettes inside the roxygen2 comments of a function but I'm having a hard time understanding how to do it.

More generally, how do we reference documents inside `/inst/doc`? E.g. I'd like to reference `/inst/doc/mypdf.pdf` inside the roxygen2 comments for `myFunc`. What would that look like? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just tell people to run the code that opens the vignette:

```
#' For more details see the help vignette:
#' \code{vignette("help", package = "mypkg")}
```

Answer (score 13):

I know this is 4 years old...and hadley provided the answer...but I'd like to offer another  option:

```
\href{../doc/help.html}{\code{vignette("help", package = "mypkg")}}
```

This gives a direct link to opening the vignette, and provides the code to show the user how to open it on their own.

Comment: I'd take back this recommendation if you are using pkgdown. pkgdown will turn the `\code{vignette("help", package = "mypkg")}` directly to a url to the vignette article (ie..using what was recommended above)