# Linking vignette within R package help documentation

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, vignette

I want to link vignette documentation within help file documentation in the roxygen headers of a function. I have tried to use the code:

```
\link[=./doc/vignette.html]{User Manual}
```

However, when I build the package and click the link I get the following output:

```
URL '/help/library/IDASData/help/IDASData/doc/get_semesters_definition.html' not found
```

Does anyone know how to properly link vignettes within the help documentation of an R package?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649124/reference-package-vignettes-with-roxygen2

Comment: The code in that post doesn't work